# Doctrine arrayCollection check if members are instanceof

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

When I declare a method I declare the type of an argument:

```
public function doOnce(CoolParam $param) {...}
```

But when I have a Doctrine ArrayCollection I can only check for the array

```
public function doOMulti(ArrayCollection $params) {...}
```

Now I would like to be sure, that all members of ArrayCollection are instance of CoolParam. Therefore I can loop the whole Array and check with `$param instanceof CoolParam`.

But is there a way to use a ArrayCollection method for this case? Just something like

```
$params->membersAreInstanceOf('CoolParam');
```

Comment: You should check each object before the insertion in a collection. Can I ask you why/when you need to check your collection?

Comment: ArrayCollection has a filter method: `$params = $params->filter(function($e) { return $e instanceof CoolParam; });`

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use the `ArrayCollection` inside of another class to enforce the type of the elements in the collection.

For example

```
class UsersCollection
{
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->users->add($user);
    }
}
```

You would then know that all elements in `public function doOMulti(UsersCollection $params) {...}` will be of the correct type.